# SharePoint Online Page with Doc Library web part missing "Add shortcut to One Drive"

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, web-part, modern-experience, onedrive

I'm using SharePoint Online with Modern interfaces.

I created a new page to which I added a new section.  In that section I added a web part for a Document Library.  The settings for the Web Part have `Show command Bar` turned on.

When I view the Document Library directly, the command bar has the following buttons: `New`, `Upload`, `Edit in grid view`, `Sync`, `Add shortcut to OneDrive`, `Pin to Quick access`, `Export to Excel` (and other automate/alert related buttons)

When I view the Document library inside the page, the command bar is there, but it is missing the `Add shortcut to OneDrive`, and `Pin to Quick access`.

For this particular library, I like to tell the users that they can quickly get to the library by adding the `Shortcut to OneDrive` (shows up on the desktop) or `Pin to Quick Access` (OneDrive web interface).  But both of these buttons are missing when the library is displayed inside a page.  Is there a way to bring them back?

My current work around is to click `See all` which will bring you to the actual doc library, and then the buttons show up, but I would prefer the more direct rout of having the buttons on the page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint default capabilities at this time - this is a limitation by Microsoft.

You cannot show `Add shortcut to OneDrive` or `Pin to Quick access` commands in [Document library web part](https://support.microsoft.com/office/use-the-document-library-web-part-a9dfecc3-2050-4528-9f00-2c5afc5731b0?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) added on site pages because document library web part does not support all the functionalities which are available in default library page.

If you want Microsoft to provide these options for default document library web part as well, you can add feedback/idea at: [SharePoint Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

Until then you will have to use the "see all" link to go to default library page and use those options from library command bar (as you are doing currently).

**Related Read**: [Show/Hide See all link from SharePoint list/library web parts](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/11/18/show-hide-see-all-link-from-sharepoint-list-library-web-parts/)